# Best way to to pass the output of a function to child components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a parent component with a data object `config` as below:

```
data() {
   return {
       config: {
            Groups: [
              {
                name: "A",
                Types: [
                  { mask: 1234, name: "Alice", type: 1},
                  { mask: 5678, name "Bob", type: 1},
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "B",
                Types: [
                  { mask: 9876, name: "Charlie", type: 2},
                  { mask: 5432, name "Drake", type: 2},
                ]
              }
            ],
        },
        Defaults: {
          dummyBoolean: false,
          dummyNumber: 1
        }
      }
   }
}
```

There are also 2 child components that for each of them, I want to pass the `Types` array (within each elements of the Groups object) if `each_element.name == child component's name`.

What I've done so far is having a computed function for each of the components as follows (which is highly inefficient):

```
      computed: {
        dataSender_A() {
          let array= []
          this.config.Groups.forEach( element => {
            if (element.name === "A") array = element.Types
          });
          return array
        },
        dataSender_B() {
          let array= []
          this.config.Groups.forEach( element => {
            if (element.name === "B") array = element.Types
          });
          return array
        },
      }
```

I'm looking for a better alternative to make this happen (as I might have more child components) and two approaches I tried so far have failed.

1. Having only one `computed` function that takes the component's name as argument and can be passed like `<child-component-A :types="dataSender('A')" />`  `<child-component-B :types="dataSender('B')" />` (As it throws error dataSender is not a function)

```
      computed: {
        dataSender: function(groupName) {
          let array= []
          this.config.Groups.forEach( element => {
            if (element.name === groupName) array = element.Types
          });
          return array
        },
      }
```

2. Having the above function in `methods` and pass that as props to child components (As it passes the function itself, not the outputted array)

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The computed properties don't accept parameters that are involved in the calculation, In this case you could just use a method like :

```
 methods: {
        dataSender: function(groupName) {
          let array= []
          this.config.Groups.forEach( element => {
            if (element.name === groupName) array = element.Types
          });
          return array
        },
      }
```